# Should my view models be with my domain entities at the core in an onion architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, n-tier-architecture, onion-architecture

Or should they be in the top layer (client UI)?
When using a onion architecture (ASP.Net MVC) should I put my view models with all my domain entities at the core. Just like in the picture below?

My question is - if yes then when I pass up a view model from my service to my client, isn't the client (top layer) dependent apon the core layer, which is two layers down and wouldn't that break the whole dependency thing with each layer only talking to the layer below it?

What happens when I have a viewmodel (in presentation layer) that needs to reference a entity in the domain layer (two layers down), doesn't this break the onion architecture of only referencing the layer directly below.

```
public class YogaSpaceListViewModel
{
    // YogaSpaceResults is in the domain layer two layers down
    public IPagedList<YogaSpaceResults> YogaSpaces { get; set; }

    public string LocationResults { get; set; }
}


// this is in the domain layer with all my other entities
// this is being filled by entity framework in the DAL, which I'm calling from the service layer.
public class YogaSpaceResults
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DbGeography LocationPoints { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO, view model belongs to the view. Each UI will have a different set of view models. Sometimes they may be similar to the domain model, but while a domain model represents a concept, view model is just a DTO to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It works from outside to inside so, Client knows about Services not viceversa, Services knows about Domain Model not viceversa.

So you are right if you put your ViewModels in the Client side how would Services know about that? Well .. under this context you are talking about Application Services not Domain Services because these serve to the domain model using the ubiquitous language and ViewModels shouldn't be part of it. 
Application services should be in the application layer wich is between client and domain model they may coordinate operations between other services and repositories. Thats why I would say that your ViewModels should be in the application layer.

Comment: Ok that is the assumption I'll make as well, based on your response and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531846/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-view-model. BUT, what about a viewmodel that has a domain entity in it? Code pasted above. Now my appliaction layer (top layer) needs to reference the domain layer which is two layers down. Is this ok to do or can I only have access to the layer directly below me?

Comment: No, the **View**(hint!!) Model belongs to UI. The application layer which makes sense only when updating the model (not for queries), knows about the operation result which _can_ be used as a view model or it can be the base for a view model, and that's the controller's job.

Comment: @user1186050 Your view model shouldn't contain a domain entity. If it does it's either bad design or you have a CRUD app and things are much simpler then.

Comment: So what would need to be changed based on my layering here. My layering looks like this. UI -> Service -> (DAL and Entities) and I've posted my viewmodel above

Comment: @user1186050 Don't think in layers, think in responsibilities and use cases. Who's on top on who is not important. Besides, the onion architecture begs for a dependency injection container.

Comment: @user1186050 First of you dont use Entities in the View or ViewModel its not recommended unless its a very simple app. 

Second, Entities are not optimized for querys and shouldnt be used for that. Dont model entities thinking about how you would query against them instead create query objects easy to consume. Model Entities to represent the business process in a easy way and to keep their state free of invariants in each transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated post, you are basically asking about a query scenario. First of all you should be very clear about what kind of operation you're doing: a command (update model) or a query (read model). Each case has their own specifics and can be optimized in a maintainable form.

In this specific case, the query, things are very simple: the controller should invoke a query service (aka query handler),similar to an application service but for querying purposes, which will get the data from persistence in the desired form. Note that in a DDD/CQRS app layering is secondary to vertical slicing aka components. This means your persistence knows about your view model and the query handler returns the view model directly from the db, there is no domain entity involved.

In a nutshell, for querying purposes the UI talks directly to persistence, skiping the Domain.